# Insert data to different table in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have 2 tables.

**Table 1: (person_identity)**

```
Id_person(PK), name, address, telp
```

**Table 2: (Student)**

```
Id_person(FK), no_student (PK), status, parent
```

How to input data to name, address, no_student, parent and status at the same time with the same Id_person but at 2 different table?

Comment: Do one insert. Then do another insert. I'm not sure where the confusion lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can do like this

```
$dataPersonIdentity = ['name' => 'Abc', 'address' => 'This is address', 'telp' => 'this is telp'];
$this->db->insert('person_identity',$dataPersonIdentity);
$personIdentityId = $this->db->insert_id();

$dataStudent = ['Id_person' => $personIdentityId, 'no_student' => 8, 'status' => 1, 'parent' => 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

do insert in the first table (person_identity)
and then do insert in the second table (student)